# Show and hide content once tweet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

I am working on a way to hide the twitter button once clicked on show new content, I thought I had it working but its still not. I am not sure why if someone could point out my mistake that would help.
Thanks.

**----UPDATE----**

its when I add this script it stops working

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

and

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

**----UPDATE END----**

Here's the code:

```js
(function($) {

  var win = null;

  $.fn.tweetAction = function(options, callback) {

    // Default parameters of the tweet popup:

    options = $.extend({
      url: window.location.href
    }, options);

    return this.click(function(e) {

      if (win) {
        // If a popup window is already shown,
        // do nothing;
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      }

      var width = 550,
        height = 350,
        top = (window.screen.height - height) / 2,
        left = (window.screen.width - width) / 2;

      var config = [
        'scrollbars=yes', 'resizable=yes', 'toolbar=no', 'location=yes',
        'width=' + width, 'height=' + height, 'left=' + left, 'top=' + top
      ].join(',');

      // Opening a popup window pointing to the twitter intent API:
      win = window.open('http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?' + $.param(options),
        'TweetWindow', config);

      // Checking whether the window is closed every 100 milliseconds.
      (function checkWindow() {

        try {
          // Opera raises a security exception, so we
          // need to put this code in a try/catch:

          if (!win || win.closed) {
            throw "Closed!";
          } else {
            setTimeout(checkWindow, 100);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          // Executing the callback, passed
          // as an argument to the plugin.

          win = null;
          callback();
        }

      })();

      e.preventDefault();
    });
  };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#tweetLink').tweetAction({
    text: 'First tweet',
    url: '#',
    via: 'website'
  }, function() {


    $('hidden-text')
      .show();

    $(".hidden-text").removeClass("hidden-text");


  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function() {
    $(this).hide("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Tweet to show content.
  <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=your_twitter" class="twitter-mention-button" id="tweetLink" data-show-count="false">Tweet to @your_twitter</a>
            </p>
            <p class="hidden-text">thank you for tweeting !</p>
```

**UPDATE**
Optimised some js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#tweetLink').tweetAction({
    text: 'First tweet',
    url: '#',
    via: 'website'
}, function () {

    $('hidden-text')
        .show("slow");

    $(".hidden-text").removeClass("hidden-text");
    $("#hide-me").hide("slow");
});
```

});

**UPDATE 3**

Ok looking at the console I seem to be getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tweetAction is not a function
```

I have updated my Jquery CDN, when i click on Tweet to @your_twitter it now dose not open in a new window but changes the url in the same window. any ideas ?

**Solved**

I had to remove some CDN's

```
 <link href="https://get.gridsetapp.com/35679/" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>    -->
<!--<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>-->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" ></script>-->
```

Comment: I edited your question to have your code as snippet, and it seems to work properly... have you tested different browsers?

Comment: Hmm im on the latest chrome, will try again. thanks

Comment: Ahh no, I have discovered the problem, please see updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it stops working when you add these scripts, add the scripts one by one and check your js console for errors. This should give you the hints to know where to search for the error.

Also check if those libraries are not loaded twice. If you've already loaded another jQuery library e.g., it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I see two syntax here but they don't have to do with your problem.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=your_twitter" class="twitter-mention-button"
               id="tweetLink" data-show-count="false">Tweet to @your_twitter/a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=your_twitter" class="twitter-mention-button"
               id="tweetLink" data-show-count="false">Tweet to @your_twitter </a> <!--Closing the tag-->

$('.hidden-text').show(); //class picker
```